# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child. When i use a child property

Tags: reactjs, json

I am getting this error in my react app:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render
> a collection of children, use an array instead.

In my react Component i called an API and getting a reasponse as a Json like this:

```
{    
title: "myTitle",
description: "My Description",
...
state: {
    id: 1,
    stateTitle: "active"
  },
}
```

I can use all the proberties, but not the property from the child object.

```
const myComponent = () => {

    ...useEffect...API call...



    return (
        <div>
             <h1>{data.title}</h1> <<--- This works fine... 
             <span>{data.state.stateTitle}</span> <<--- here i am getting the error
        </div>

    );
}

export default myComponent;
```

i tried to display the values with the JSON.stringify() methode, this works also fine.

```
<span>{JSON.stringify(data.state)}</span> // result: {"id":i,"stateTitle":"active"}
```

Or print with console.log(data.state.stateTitle); works as expected..

Why i am getting this error, when i try to print the value from a child element.

Comment: If you are certain that the line indicated is giving you an error, the only possible explanation is that `stateTitle` is not a string.

Comment: @Adam thx for your hint. I checked with console.log(typeof data.state.stateTitle). --> result: string :/

Comment: I believe you have initialised `data` with a default value which is probably failing in the render part. The component renders the division with that default `data` before calling the API. Once the API response is received, the component will get re-rendered with the fetched response. Can you share what you are initialising `data` with?

Comment: @himayan WOW! you're right! I copied data from my list component "const [data, setData] = useState([]);". i remove "[] from "useState([])" (i dont get an array) and now it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @EdiG. Great! Let me move it to an answer below. Whoever stumbles upon a problem like this would probably have a less hard time going through answers, if there is an accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have initialised `data` with a default value which is probably failing in the render part. The component renders the division with that default `data` before calling the API. Once the API response is received, the component will get re-rendered with the fetched response.